# How to display blocked roads in Bing Maps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, windows-phone-7.1

I am working for an application of an event. I have integrated Bing Maps (Road View) in the application to make people reach the venue.

But, due to the event certainly nearby roads will be blocked on the day of the event.

So I want to display the road blocks, such that any user does not take a blocked road by looking at the directions from the map.

Please suggest what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a pushpin to the map at each location where a road is/will be closed.

Details of how to add pushpins at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588383(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: +1 for simple and lightweight. You could use a style to retemplate the pushpin with a yellow/black striped blockade horse; writing ROADBLOCK on a standard pushpin would be a bit intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion, you could create GPX tracks of those roads that will be blocked. ( look online for GPX creators or use a GPS logger )
And when you have this information, you can load those tracks upon the map with a special colour...

A GPX file will contain TrackSegments and they contain Trackpoints, which have Latitude and Longitude.
The trick is to read out those points and create LocationCollection object, that can be show on the map!

Example:

```
LocationCollection trackLocations = new LocationCollection();
var t = from trackSegment in selectedTrack.TrackSegments
        select new GeoCoordinate(Double.Parse(trackSegment.Latitude), Double.Parse(trackSegment.Longitude));
```